# Software to zip big files in small pieces

Tags: macos, mac, zip

Is there any program on Mac which can zip big files in small pieces (free ones are preferred)?

Answer (score 5):

Any command-line archiving tool can do this when combined with the split command:

gzip example:

```
tar cf – |gzip -9 -c |split -b 100M split_archive.tgz.
```

The files generated will look like:

```
split_archive.tgz.aa
split_archive.tgz.ab
...
```

To put them back together, use `cat split_archive.tgz*`

If you already made an 'Archive.zip' of some files using the right click menu, you can split it after the fact by typing in a terminal:

```
split -b 500m Archive.zip split_archive.zip.
```

Answer (score 3):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) can do this, and it's open source and free.

You can find the Mac OS X downloads towards the bottom of the page.

Comment: I was checking this but have not find any info regarding this on their website.

Comment: @itsaboutcode - Their website is very lacking when it comes to documentation of what 7-zip can do. But my windows version of 7-zip can split large archives into smaller so I assume the mac version can do the same.